# Rich Text Editor that only allows simple formatting like bold and links, even on paste

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

Is there a rich text editor that allows simple commands like bold, italic, links but NO color, font size changes, font family changes, images, etc. This needs to also work on paste as those NO formatting items must up the look of the site when end users do it.

Currently I am using TinyMCE but open to anything else that maybe able to do this, including options in TinyMCE.